# nodejs + express + swig: how do I check the request before rendering?

Tags: node.js, express, swig-template

To be honest, I don't really know how nodejs, express, and swig work.
I have this code that seems to serve up all my html pages

```
app.engine('html', swig.renderFile);
app.set('view engine', 'html');
app.set('views', __dirname+'/html');
```

I'd like to be able to examine the request before returning the html file. Specifically, I want to check if the user is using an older version of IE and redirect them to another page instead.

Now, I can examine the request and redirect for specific pages like so

```
app.get('/veryspecificpage.html', function(req, res) {
  if( isBadBrowser(req) ) {
    res.writeHead(302, {
      'Location': 'browserError.html'
    });
    res.end();
  } else {
    res.render('veryspecificpage', {});
  });
})
```

But I don't want to have to specify this for every single .html page. How do I intercept the request and do this for all html pages?

Comment: `console.log(req); `

Comment: I probably didn't state my question clearly. But how do I intercept the request in the first place--in the app.engine() or app.set() calls or something else?

Comment: The request is made at the URI so you would do it after `app.get('/veryspecificpage.html', function(req, res) {`

Comment: I am not trying to be mean but you shouldn't be using these tools if you don't know how they work.  They are very complex if you don't know what is going on.  I recommend [this book](http://www.amazon.com/Practical-Node-js-Building-Real-World-Scalable-ebook/dp/B00IGKE2FK) that brought me up to speed.  You should have a clear understanding of REST and MVC before touching Node.js

Comment: Yes that's what I'm already doing now (it's in my post). I'm asking is there a general way to do it for ALL pages without having to specify each one individually

Comment: And thank you for the resource. I will take a look though I am already quite familiar with REST and MVC, just not in nodejs

Comment: @Rafael I disagree with you.  Node.js/Express/Swig are some of the easiest tools I've ever used.  I've also taught a lot of folks how to use them.  Believe it or not, it's pretty easy for the folks that have never coded before to pick them up.  I've had a harder time teaching folks who are used to building web applications in different stacks.

Comment: @kane I'm not sure of the intent of your application, but if you are simply detecting compatibility issues, I strongly recommend finding another way to do it.  There are plenty of browsers out there that will not support newer functionality, and they aren't IE.  Better to detect what your browser can do, than assume that you know all of the browsers in the world and their compatibility with your site.  Modernizr is a good tool for detecting feature support.

Comment: @Brad it's ok to disagree.  But there are many fundamental concepts that a newbie cannot grasp that will leave air pockets in their applications and vulnerabilities.  A lot of newbies don't understand REST, MVC, and HTTP yet alone Node.  I wouldn't let a newbie touch node at all.

Comment: @Rafael All of those concepts are present in other stacks as well.  Node.js is no different, other than that it gives new folks a straightforward and simple way to get started.  Then as they move to writing client-side code, they already have learned to use JavaScript properly.  We should never discourage someone from trying to learn.  Node.js is just as accessible to new folks as Rails or PHP.

Comment: Like I said it is in node therefore should be learn prior to usage ;) I am all for someone trying to learn something but it would help them in the long run to learn the fundamentals first and not along the way.  Either way is up to the end user and how much work they are willing to put in to get caught up fast.

Comment: Gentlemen, I didn't mean for my new-to-nodejs comment to take this discussion off track. Brad is right in suspecting that I'm not a newbie in programming. I have nearly a decade of experience in other stacks, but I am still learning nodejs. With my limited experience with nodejs, I've been able to set up several REST calls, make async Promises to fetch mongo data, and serve up dynamic pages. But more learning is not a bad thing

Comment: @Brad Thanks for letting me know about Modernizr. I was using jReject but it depends on jquery. I'm on jQuery 2.0 so IE8 and earlier just barfs which is why I needed a server-side solution for just IE. But I think Modernizr will do the trick

Answer (score 1):

**Log each request**

Sample node web server.  Simply log each request to the server like this...

```
var http = require('http');

http.createServer(function (req, res) {

  console.log(req); // <--- LOGS EACH REQUEST 

  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
  res.end('Hello World\n');
}).listen(1337, '127.0.0.1');
console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:1337/');
```

Comment: is this compatible with express? I believe this is how I start my server:
var app = express().
How does what you suggest work with that?

Comment: Since you are using express you would need to use middleware like @mreitas suggested.

Answer (score 1):

You should use middleware to check every request.

```
// gets executed for every request to the app
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  // check for browser here and redirect if necessary, if not, next() will continue to other middleware/route.
  next();
});
```

Make sure you place it before any route. You can learn more about it by going to [this](http://expressjs.com/guide/using-middleware.html) page.

Comment: I tried this, but my redirect is going into an infinite loop. Maybe I'm not doing redirect correctly in my original post?

Comment: @kane you should be using res.redirect([status], url) to make you're redirects...